# How does the `palette` argument to `scale_x_discrete` work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't understand what the `palette` argument to `scale_x_discrete` is supposed to do. The manual says it should accept something like `scales::hue_pal()` but this gives me an error. Does this work at all, or is this just an artifact from the interface to `discrete_scale`?

How does this argument work? How can I make the second example work, if it is possible at all?

```r
# loading libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(scales)

# works:
ggplot(penguins, aes(x=island, y=bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = str_to_upper # just as an example
  )

# does not work:
ggplot(penguins, aes(x=island, y=bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = str_to_upper,
    palette = scales::hue_pal()
  )
```

Comment: `scale_x_discrete` has an identity palette (i.e. does not transform). The documentation is there because arguments are being forwarded to the `discrete_scale()` function, which allows that argument for colour scales.